# Does pthread_exit kill a thread.. I mean free the stack allocated to it?

Tags: pthreads

I want to create a lot of threads for a writing into a thread, and after writing I call exit... But, when I call exit do I free up the stack or do I still consume it??

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid resource leaks, you have to do one of these 2:

- Make sure some other thread call pthread_join() on the thread
- Create the thread as 'detached', which can either be done by setting the proper pthread attribute to pthread_create, or by calling the pthread_detach() function.

Failure to do so will often result in the entire stack "leaking" in many implementations.

Comment: pthread_join will halt the parent thread until the child exits... but, if I make the child thread as detach it will not halt for the child thread to exit right???..

Comment: If you make it detachable, you should not pthread_join() on it.

Comment: Ya, I got your point, I just want to confirm will pthread_detach halt the parent thread until the child finishes the process.

Comment: So, you mean pthread_join also blocks the parent thread and even pthread_detach blocks the parent thread...

Comment: @Invicus Sorry for the confusion. 1. pthread_detach does not block. 2. pthread_join will block the thread that calls pthread_join(), that is: pthread_join() returns when the thread you join on finishes. 3. Do not call pthread_join on a thread that is detached.

Comment: But, I think the pthread detach does not clear up the stack I guess... Because I am using it, and I am seeing that the thread is not been cleared from the stack...

Comment: @Invictus  Perhaps you're using it wrong. How do you see that things are not cleared up ?

Answer (score 0):

The system allocates underlying storage for each thread, (thread ID, thread retval, stack), and this will remain in the process space (and not be recycled) until the thread has terminated and has been joined by other threads.

If you have a thread which you don't care how the thread terminates, and a detached thread is a good choice.
For detached threads, the system recycles its underlying resources automatically after the thread terminates.

source article: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-memory-leaks/